# Magento 2 - Customer sometimes receiving 503 Error when performing random actions on the cart

Tags: magento2, cart, quote, cookie, 503

I'm experiencing an issue where customers are intermittently receiving a 503 error (maintenance flag) when performing certain actions on the cart in Magento 2.

For example, in one scenario, a guest user adds a product to the cart, proceeds to the login page, logs in, and then navigates back to the cart. Upon loading the available shipping methods in the cart, the customer may encounter a 503 error. However, upon refreshing the page, the error disappears.

Another scenario involves a guest user adding a product to the cart, proceeding to the login page, logging in, and then applying a coupon code for free shipping on the cart page. In this case, the customer receives a 503 error upon applying the coupon code, but after refreshing the page, the error is resolved, and the coupon code can be successfully applied.

I have checked the logs, but there are no errors related to this issue.

Could you please provide guidance on what could be causing this issue and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The intermittent 503 error (maintenance flag) you're experiencing in certain scenarios could be caused by various factors. Here are some possible causes and steps to troubleshoot and resolve the issue:

1. Insufficient server resources: Check if your server has enough resources (CPU, memory, disk space) to handle the increased traffic or resource-intensive tasks. You may need to upgrade your server or optimize its configuration.
2. Caching issues: If you have caching enabled, ensure that it is properly configured and cleared when necessary. Clear the cache manually or configure automatic cache clearing after specific events (e.g., product updates, cart changes).

3 Load balancer or proxy misconfiguration: If you're using a load balancer or reverse proxy, verify its configuration to ensure it is properly forwarding requests to your Magento application servers.

4. Backend service timeouts: Check if there are any backend services (payment gateways, shipping providers) that are taking too long to respond. Adjust the timeouts or contact the respective service providers for assistance.
5. Custom code or third-party extensions: Review any custom code or third-party extensions that are involved in the affected scenarios. Disable them temporarily and test if the issue persists. If the issue is resolved, contact the extension developers for support or consider alternative solutions.
6. Session-related issues: Verify that your session storage (e.g., file system, Redis, database) is configured correctly and functioning properly. Check if there are any session-related errors in the logs and ensure that session files are not being deleted prematurely.
7. Debugging and monitoring: Enable Magento's developer mode to get more detailed error messages and logging. Monitor your server logs, web server logs, and Magento logs for any relevant information when the issue occurs.
8. Magento version and patches: Ensure that you're using the latest stable version of Magento and have applied any relevant security patches. Upgrade your Magento installation if necessary.

Hope it helps you..!